# Django model related_list with list view

Tags: django, model, django-queryset, django-select-related

First, I have a student model and a counseling model.
There are hundreds of consultation models in one student model.
I'd like to make the last consultation date for each subject(classification) into a listview for each student.
If  make it , teacher can see at a glance who consulted the longest and who consulted the most recently.

is there any way?

consultation model.py

```
class Consultation(models.Model):
    classification = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=CLASSIFICATION,  # there are 'korean', 'english', 'math', 'etc ... '
        default='etc',
    )
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=False, verbose_name='contentt')
    created_to = models.ForeignKey(
        Student,
        related_name='consultations',
        verbose_name='student',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name='time')
```

student mnodel.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='이름')
```

I want to user ListView if i can

```
class StudentList(ListView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'student/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'students'
    paginate_by = 10
    blah blah blah
```

What i want to make is like

| student name | last consultation date of korea subject | last consultation date of english subject | last consultation date of math subject |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| student name | last consultation date of korea subject | last consultation date of english subject | last consultation date of math subject |  |
| student name | last consultation date of korea subject | last consultation date of english subject | last consultation date of math subject |  |
| student name | last consultation date of korea subject | last consultation date of english subject | last consultation date of math subject |  |
| student name | last consultation date of korea subject | last consultation date of english subject | last consultation date of math subject |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='이름')
    
    def last_consult_korean(self):
        last_date=self.consultations.filter(classification='korean').order_by('-created_at').first()
        return last_date.created_at if last_date else ''
```

write a function like this in your model, and in your template call like `{{ student.last_consult_korean }}`

Comment: but how can i make ordering by last_date_korean ? in template?

Comment: tyring ordering  but ... no such column: student.last_consult_date_korean :<

Comment: it doesn't work that way its a function not a field.

Comment: With the models you have it seems there is no easy solution. You need to take a look the the sorted method of python and use it to sort the results.

Comment: another thing you can try is that use ConsultationListView instead of StudentListView. Then it might be possible to order based on the created_at field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227966/discussion-between-sandeep-balagopal-and-chea).

Comment: hey @chea Please accept the answer if it worked for the original question.

Comment: i solved it with js to ordering that list, thanks man